# Multidimensional partial integration without the divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, compactness

I have the following question:

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and connected, but not fit for the divergence theorem, only use the formula for partial integraion. Let $u\in C(\Omega),\,V\in C^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R^n})$, where one of these has compact support in $\Omega$. Show that:

$\int_\Omega V\cdot\nabla u \, dx=-\int_\Omega u \;div(V)\,dx$.

What I thought of was using the product rule of the divergence:

$div(V\cdot u)=div(V)\cdot u+ V\cdot \nabla u$ and integrating this over $\Omega$ to get:

$\int_\Omega div(V\cdot u)\, dx=\int_\Omega div(V)\cdot u \, dx+ \int_\Omega V\cdot \nabla u \, dx$

And the left hand side equals $0$ since one of those functions has compact support in $\Omega$? I know it is grasping for straws but I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe use that $V \cdot \nabla u = \sum_{i=1}^n V_i \partial_i u$ and then use your formula for partial integration ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't see how it leads to the wanted results...

Answer (score 2):

Using what I explained in the commentary, you have :

\begin{aligned}
 \int_{\Omega} V \cdot \nabla u  & = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\Omega} V_i \partial_i u \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n (-\int_{\Omega} \partial_i V_i u + \underbrace{\int_{\partial \Omega} V_i \ u \ n_i}_{=0} ) \text{ using integration by parts}\\
& = - \int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i V_i u\\
& = \int_{\Omega} div(V) u
\end{aligned}

I only used the first integration by parts formule but I assumed that is what you are reffering to when you mention *"the formula for partial integration"*.